# && Operator precendence in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
if(e.FN === ' ' && e.GN === ' ' && e.LN === ' ' && e.DB === ' '){
```

This condition is never evaluated at all. Is this the way to check if all the values are null.

Comment: What do you mean "condition is never evaluated"?  Do you mean, it never evaluates to true?  You may want to use `if(!e.FN && !e.GN && !e.LN && !e.DB) { ... }`

Comment: @Aleks if he wanted all of the operands evaluated, the use of a single & would work. if(e.FN === null & e.GN === null & e.LN === null & e.DB === null) and is much more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you are checking if those values are all equal to a Space.  The === not only compares the values but ensures they are the same type.  However, if e.FN is null both `e.FN == ' ' and e.FN === ' "` will always return false.  I think what you want is

```
if(e.FN === null && e.GN === null && e.LN === null && e.DB === null)
```

or even better, if you don't care if they are null, undefined or 0 you could do

```
if(e.FN && e.GN && e.LN && e.DB)
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if(e.FN === null && e.GN === null && e.LN === null && e.DB === null){
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if all the values are null you should do:

```
if(e.FN === null && e.GN === null && e.LN === null && e.DB === null){
```

if the first value is not null javascript doesn't evaluate other condition, because if the first condition is false it's not possible for all the conditions to be true.